# cant run python scripts without typing "python" in windows comand prompt after installing Enthought Canopy

Tags: enthought, canopy

I used to have Enthought EPD, and I upgraded to Enthought Canopy on windows 7. My python program my_program.py wont run without typing python ("python my_program.py") in the command prompt, where before the upgrade I could run in just by typing "my_program.py". 
Thanks,
Ron

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the below code in your script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Comment: This line is the header of the script. it was there before. But with EPD I could run the script just by typing my_program.py. Now, with Canopy, I cant.